# How would I move my button in an upward position?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, css

I want to move the `About` button up to the point where it's right below the title but it won't work.

I tried:

1. In `ButtonToScroll.css`, `margin-bottom: 40%;` but it didn't work
2. In `Main.css`, I did `margin-bottom: inherit;` to accompany 1, but didn't work.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

If you need any other information please let me know.

Here's a sandbox of my project https://codesandbox.io/s/github/name/Encrypt-Your-Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way in my opinion would be to give the button `position: relative` and set `top: -80px` or whatever you think looks best:

https://codesandbox.io/s/y0pm9l87x9

Answer (score 1):

Set in ButtonToScroll.css

```
.about { margin-bottom: 10% }
```

and remove in Main.css

```
.boxSkull { margin-top: 10% }
```

Furthermore you should have only one `<body>` tag in html document.

Answer (score 0):

Add a value in `ButtonToScroll.css` under `text-decoration: none;` called:

```
margin-top: -10%;
```

It will move everything up from the About button downwards.

Comment: that won't work because it'll move the textarea and was random text along with it.  I only want to move the about button, nothing else

Comment: @sp92 Do what @Chase DeAnda suggested. `position: relative` and `top: -50px` -50px would be right under the title